# Управление через хостовую машину Windows XP виртуальной машиной Linux (сервером)

Tags: ubuntu, kohana, virtualbox

Всем привет! 
Недавно начал изучать Linux. Работаю на Windows XP. Так, что вопросы могут показаться ламерскими:)

Установил VirtualBox с ОС Ubuntu Linux. 
Я хочу запустить сервер на своей виртуальной машине.

Как сделать, что бы он был доступен в браузерах хостовой машины Windows? 
А так же, возможно ли редактировать файлы сервера (движка (пишу на kohana), демонов) через Windows? Я использую NetBeans.

Я знаю, что на VirtualBox есть раздел "Общие папки". Я уже создал папку а так же смог синхронизировать их. 
Как мне подсказывает логика - алгоритм редактирования следующий: 
- Я редактирую сервер на Windows полностью скопировав проект в виртуальную папку. 
- Далее захожу на сервер, и через Linux консоль выполняю команду, которая переносит файлы на сервер из "shared" папки.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно это делать! Или линк на статью.. Не хочется изобретать велосипед..
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В VirtualBox в настройке сети лучше выбрать для сетевого адаптера тип подключения "сетевой мост". 

Если VB (и винда) на английском, то IMHO там надо выбирать "bridge" (но точно термины в этом списке не помню).

Для доступе по виртуалке по имени можете отредактировать 

c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 2):

Организуйте локальную сеть  между хостовой и виртуальной операционками и обращайтесь к серверу по его IP

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.